# javascript: way to get the last value returned in the interpreter

Tags: javascript, interpreter

I'm trying to find a way to programatically get the last value returned by the Javascript interpreter. Ruby's interpreter, to name an example, has the "_":

```
1 + 2 #=> 3
_ #=> 3
```

I would like to know if the same thing exists in Javascript.

EDIT:

Another way to maybe achieve this. Is there any syntax that supports the continuation of an expression in a newline? Something like this:

```
var a = \&
    1 + 2;
a #=> 3
```

Some sort of combination of characters that tell the interpreter the expression continues in a newline (like the + for string concatenation).

PURPOSE:

Purpose of this research is to find if I can load a JSON data structure using a script tag and successfully assign it from outside of its scope, something like this:

```
<script> var json_struct = </script>
<script src="http://domain.com/myjsonfile.json" type='application/json' ></script>
```

which, by the way, doesn't work. Surprisingly :)

Comment: In what environment? In node, in the terminal, it's exactly as you've mentioned in your question.

Comment: well, all environments, all interpreters (if all scripts get interpreted by the browser interpreter, then I would like to use it in my scripts as well, I would definitely find some use for it).

Comment: No such thing. In fact, you can't even use _ in Ruby or Python because it's a special value the REPL assigns to after evaluating the last expression. It's not available for use in scripts because program execution may not necessarily be deterministic, thus there's no "last" value. The closest thing you can do in Ruby or Python is to get the last stack frame inside a function. There's no such thing either in the Ecmascript spec as this is implementation dependent.

Comment: I've edited the question, maybe you have something to say regarding it.

Comment: Still confused what you are trying to achieve. You can format the code anyway you want in JS as long as the line doesn't end at a terminal. Read the ECMAScript grammar to find out what the terminals are.

Comment: @Y.HWong I just wrote the purpose of my research, maybe you have some more inputs about the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> PURPOSE:
>
> Purpose of this research is to find if I can load a JSON data structure
>   using a script tag and successfully assign it from outside of its scope

There is no construct in browser based javascript that can do this.

The reason is that browsers, since the earliest Netscape days, have always initiated the script compiler upon the closing of the script tag. Regardless if it's javascript, VBscript (IE only) or Tcl (with the appropriate plugin).

Which means that any statement that is incomplete will simply be treated as a syntax error. Each `<script>` tag is basically treated as a single file.

What you're trying to do is similar to this in Ruby:

```
a = require 'one_plus_two.rb'
```

which I don't think works in Ruby.

---

However, in non-browser environments that support modules like Node.js, the method that imports module does in fact return a value (usually an object). So you can do something like this in node.js:

```
var a = require('my_data_file.js');
```

Unfortunately, the `require` function only works on local files. But Node.js is open source so you can always fork it and modify `require` to be able to source from `http://` like PHP.

Alas, if what you're trying to do is browser scripting then the above point is moot.

Comment: great answer, that clears some points. Now, let's say I'd have a script tag loading a js file having only "var a = " as content. Let's say I'd have a script tag afterwards loading my json file. Now let's say both of the scripts are marked as defered. Shouldn't in the defer case both scripts be evaluated by the script compiler as if they were one?

Comment: This is a really long answer that says very little. What does it have to do with Node and Netscape? The simplest answer is that each script tag forms an evaluation context - meaning all the stuff inside the script tag is given as a string to eval() as a program tree, which is then parsed. You cannot execute anything that can't be parsed as a valid JS program inside a script tag. That is all. Everything else is irrelevant.

Comment: @ChuckE: no. Defered only delays the execution of the script. Each script is compiled separately. As such, the json data is a valid script but the `var a =` is a syntax error.

Comment: @Y.HWong: That's exactly what I said without using technical jargon (I assumed the OP is more familiar with Ruby so I gave examples that may be familiar to him). I try to avoid using the word "context" when discussing javascript because it doesn't mean what it usually mean in other languages. As for Netscape - the entire design if the javascript language is best understood in historical context (because the spec is usually written by examining how current browsers work instead of browsers written to conform to spec).

Comment: And as for Node - see his PURPOSE. He's not strictly asking how the script tag works, he want to know if there is any mechanism in JS (not necessarily using separate script tags) that can do what he wants. It turns out that Node does implement what he wants (and there's talk about future browsers adopting modules) but current browsers don't have it.

Comment: @Y.HWong both of your explanations basically cleared out what I wanted to know about the theme. My purpose was trying to load and use a json structure using a script tag pointing to a json source file. I see now that is impossible. Besides that, I've learned that each script is evaluated in its own scope regardless of whether they're all evaluated at once, and what I wanted to achieve would actually not be that possible even in Ruby. That only leaves me to question the usefulness of the script tag when filled with something other than script (java or vb).

Comment: @ChuckE: `evaluated in its own scope`. Ah, that's where you're wrong. This is the reason I did not want to use words like "scope" or "context" because they can potentially be misleading. All script tags are evaluated in **the same global scope**. But they are compiled separately. The difference is one of compilation vs execution.

Comment: true, bad choice of words. I wanted to say they are evaluated separately, not necessarily in different scopes. Still, it would be nice to have some sort of special symbol which would mean "replace me with the next evaluated expression or don't do nothing if there isn't one". Sod it, I'm a dreamer :)

Comment: @ChuckE The right word is `parsing context`. I've used the wrong word too. Evaluation means completely different thing. You are not a dreamer. You can do what you want in PHP.